# Unity multidisplay. How to make display[0] windowed and others display fullScreen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen, fullscreen

I have **3 screens** in my game. I want to show `display[0]` as a **window** with size `width=600, heigth=450` and `display[1]` and `display[2]` as **fullScreen**

So, on each scene I want to show, I have **three cameras**, main is subsribed to `display[0]`, **leftCamera** is subscribed to `display[1]`, and **rightCamera** is subscribed to `display[2]`, then **I add following the script to left and right cameras** to activate displays:

```
    //initialization
    void Start () {
        if (Display.displays.Length == 3)
        {
            Display.displays[1].Activate();
            Display.displays[2].Activate();
        }
        else if (Display.displays.Length == 2)
        {
            Display.displays[1].Activate();
        }
    }

    void Update () {            
    }
```

On the other hand I set the following on **Player settings**:

[image]

When I start game, a windowed app appears. There is a `Menu` with buttons inside a canvas, when I click a button I use:

```
        public void OnButtonClickMenu1 ()
        {
            #if UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER
               SceneManager.LoadScene ("MyScene1");
            #else
               Application.LoadLevel ("MyScene1");
            #endif
        }
```

So, when I click on menu button, **scene loads correctly on three monitors** however `display[0] maximizes`, and I would like `display[0]` **to keep windowed**

I have tried setting `SetParams` to `display[0]` inside button action like:

```
            public void OnButtonClickMenu1 ()
            {
                Display.displays[0].SetParams(600, 450, 0, 0);
                #if UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_3_OR_NEWER
                   SceneManager.LoadScene ("MyScene1");
                #else
                   Application.LoadLevel ("MyScene1");
                #endif
            }
```

But Is not working, `display[0]` keeps on maximizing...
What could I do to keep it windowed?

```
I am using Unity 2018.2.6f1
```

Comment: What platform(s) are you targeting specifically? There may not be an appropriate solution for all desktop platforms.

Comment: Forgot to tell, Main focus is PC standalone

Answer (score 1):

Replace the

```
Display.displays[0].SetParams(600, 450, 0, 0);
```

with

```
Screen.SetResolution(600, 450, false);
```

It seems the main screen goes full screen for somereason. Setting the Screen.SetResolution makes the the display[0] go out from full screen. This will not have any effect on other windows behavior.